# Concurrency pattern help - Fan in and return result?

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

I am writing up a quick concurrent integration testing package. I've already written the POC and now I'm trying to come up with a new pattern for it. I wish to adhere to the following rules for it:

- A test suite may have many tests
- A test suite must have n workers for running TestPreppers
- A test suite must have n workers for running TestValidators
- A test must pass prep before running validation
- A test may have many children
- A test must pass validation before running children tests

Here is the structure:

```
package conctest

func New() *TestSuite {
    return &TestSuite{nil, 1, 1, make(chan TestPrepper), make(chan TestValidator)}
}

type TestSuite struct {
    Tests                []*Test
    ConcurrentPreppers   int
    ConcurrentValidators int

    prepperChan   chan TestPrepper
    validatorChan chan TestValidator
}

type TestPrepper func() error
type TestValidator func() ValidatorResult

type ValidatorResult struct {
    Pass  bool
    Error error
}

type Test struct {
    Convey    string
    Details   string
    Prepper   TestPrepper
    Validator TestValidator
    MaxRuns   int
    Children  []*Test

    runs   int
    errors []error
}
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a concurrency design that meets the requirements. I need to expose a method from TestSuite that is available to Test that will allow it to send its work to the TestSuites workers as well as return the result back to the Test.

Comment: Please let me know if this needs clarification...

Comment: I've read this a number of times, and still don't really know what you're asking for. I think you've put the cart before the horse here. You defined some hierarchy of types, with somewhat confused responsibilities, and now you're trying to shoehorn in a concurrency pattern to make it work. Figure out how you're going to solve the concurrency problem first, and then work on the structure.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your input. I mainly just wanted to convey what I'm trying to accomplish by showing the existing structure, mainly the Test struct. I need a way to tie together a slice of Test and ensure that at any given time, only n Prep functions are running at a time and n Validator functions are running at a time across all of them (whether they are a child or parent test. The main pattern I'm looking to solve for is how to fan in (sending a function) and also retrieve the result of that function from the go routine it was on.

Comment: Starting from the premise that you can send an arbitrary function down a channel and somehow get the result from another goroutine is a problem (at least without requiring a specifically crafted closure).  Maybe this can be of help http://blog.golang.org/pipelines? It covers fan-in, fan-out, bounded parallelism, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. I am welcome to any criticism or better approach and will accept that answer. I created a private transport struct which contains my function and a channel in which to return the result on:

```
package conctest

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func New() *ConcTest {
    return &ConcTest{nil, 1, 1, make(chan *prepperTransport), make(chan *validatorTransport), nil}
}

type ConcTest struct {
    Tests                []*Test
    ConcurrentPreppers   int
    ConcurrentValidators int

    prepperChan   chan *prepperTransport
    validatorChan chan *validatorTransport

    testSync *sync.WaitGroup
}

func (ct *ConcTest) Run() {
    // start up prepper workers
    for i := 0; i < ct.ConcurrentPreppers; i++ {
        go func() {
            for p := range ct.prepperChan {
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
                p.Result <- p.Prepper()
            }
        }()
    }

    // start up validator workers
    for i := 0; i < ct.ConcurrentValidators; i++ {
        go func() {
            for v := range ct.validatorChan {
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
                v.Result <- v.Validator()
            }
        }()
    }

    // start parent tests, child tests will be called recursively
    ct.testSync = &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, t := range ct.Tests {
        ct.testSync.Add(1)
        go ct.runTest(t)
    }

    // wait for all tests to complete
    ct.testSync.Wait()
}

func (ct *ConcTest) runTest(t *Test) {
    // test is a pass until failure encountered
    t.Pass = true

    // run and wait for prep to finish
    pt := &prepperTransport{t.Prepper, make(chan PrepperResult)}
    ct.prepperChan <- pt
    pr := <-pt.Result

    // return on prep failure
    if pr != nil {
        t.Pass = false
        t.Errors = append(t.Errors, pr)
        ct.testSync.Done()
        return
    }

    // run the validator until pass or max runs reached
    for {
        // sleep for given frequency
        time.Sleep(t.Frequency)

        // send the validator to the queue
        t.Runs++
        vt := &validatorTransport{t.Validator, make(chan ValidatorResult)}
        ct.validatorChan <- vt

        // wait for validator response
        vr := <-vt.Result

        // append error to the test
        if vr.Error != nil {
            t.Errors = append(t.Errors, vr.Error)
        }

        // break on pass
        if vr.Pass {
            break
        }

        // break on max attempts
        if t.MaxRuns == t.Runs {
            t.Pass = false
            break
        }
    }

    // break on validator failure
    if !t.Pass {
        ct.testSync.Done()
        return
    }

    // run all children tests
    for _, c := range t.Children {
        ct.testSync.Add(1)
        go ct.runTest(c)
    }

    ct.testSync.Done()
    return
}

type Prepper func() PrepperResult
type PrepperResult error
type prepperTransport struct {
    Prepper Prepper
    Result  chan PrepperResult
}

type Validator func() ValidatorResult
type ValidatorResult struct {
    Pass  bool
    Error error
}
type validatorTransport struct {
    Validator Validator
    Result    chan ValidatorResult
}

type Test struct {
    Convey    string
    Details   string
    Frequency time.Duration
    MaxRuns   int

    Prepper   Prepper
    Validator Validator
    Children  []*Test

    Runs   int
    Errors []error
    Pass   bool
}
```